# Xamarin iOS. Can I use collection view inside of stackView control (as item of stackview)?

Tags: ios, xamarin, collectionview, stackview

I have simple application which contains `UICollectionViewController` with custom `UICollectionViewCell`. The controller is placed in Mainstoryboard (I use native xamarin). My application works, but I want to add a common  '**header**' control above of my collection view (with buttons and labels which will work with/describe collection).
I had expected, it can be done by `UIStackView` when my already created collection view would be in the bottom of StackView and my newly creted 'header' control in the top. But as I may see, I cannot add my `UICollectionViewController` as item of `Stack view`. 
I think it can be done by `TabBarController`, but it looks like it's not a good idea, especially If i have more then one a potencial control buttons for my collection view. 
Maybe there is a better solution?
Could someone advise me?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a new `UIViewController`, put a `UIStackView` in it. Then initialize your `UICollectionViewController` in `Storyboard`, add its view in the StackView:

```
UIView headerView = new UIView();
...//Add some items in this view

//Add a height constraint
headerView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(headerView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 200));
MyStack.AddArrangedSubview(headerView);

MyCollectionView collection = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyCollectionView") as MyCollectionView;
MyStack.AddArrangedSubview(collection.View);
```

But if you only want to add a header view, I recommend you to use `UICollectionView`'s `Header`.

Firstly, Use the event below to create the header in the CollectionView's
   `Source`:

```
public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    if (elementKind == "UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader" && indexPath.Section == 0)
    {
        UICollectionReusableView header = collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(new NSString("UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader"), "MyHeader", indexPath);

        //Add some items
        //header.AddSubview();

        return header;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Do not forget register the Header Class: `CollectionView.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView(typeof(UICollectionReusableView), new NSString("UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader"), "MyHeader");`

At last set the Header's height to show it:

```
// This event exists in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
public override CGSize GetReferenceSizeForHeader(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return new CGSize(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 300);
    }
    return CGSize.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `UICollectionView` as a subview to `UIStackView` by creating a `UIViewController` in storyboard and just drag and drop `UIStackView` and `UICollectionView` as a subview inside it. and assign the View Controller as the Collection View’s data source property
For Common **header** control, you might wanna a create a custom `UIView` using either `XIB` or by programmatic approach by creating a sub class of `UIView`.

so your controller hierarchy would be

```
->UIViewController
    ->UIStackView
        ->UIView
        ->UICollectionView
```

However, `UIStackView` is ideal for situation where you have a complex view hierarchy where you don't have to deal with multiple auto layout constraints by yourself, but it has some common issues you might want to look at this [post](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/36-Oddities-of-UIStackView).

If that's not the case then you should use a simpler approach and just add constraints manually to layout your views.